# SwiftUI: IOS 16 navigation stack

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I was looking at the new navigation stack in iOS 16 and it has this path that track which stack you are in.

To cycle through the list in the detail view by clicking on Go Next, I have added an index and just increment it accordingly and I wonder if this is necessary when you are using the navigation stack.  Please help me to take a look at the code below see if I can do the same thing without using index in the Company struct.  Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Company: Identifiable, Hashable {
  var id = UUID()
  var index: Int
  let name: String
  let address: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
  
  let companies: [Company] = [.init(index: 0, name: "Apple", address: "Infinity Loop"), .init(index: 1, name: "Facebook", address: "Hacker Way"), .init(index: 2, name: "Google", address: "Mountain View")]
  
  @State var index: Int = 0
  
  @State var path: [Company] = []
  
    var body: some View {
      
        VStack {
          NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            List(companies, id: \.self) { company in
              NavigationLink(company.name, value: company)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Company.self) { company in
              VStack {
                Text("\(company.index)")
                Text(company.address)
                Button {
                  print(companies.count)
                  index = company.index
                  if index == companies.count - 1 {
                    index = 0
                  } else {
                    index += 1
                  }
                  path = [companies[index]]
                } label: {
                  Text("Go Next")
                }
                Button {
                  path.removeAll()
                } label: {
                  Text("Go Home")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the index can actually be derived from the company array.

```
var theIndex = companies.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == company.id })!
```